# CSS Horizontal Circular Box Navigation Bar

Tags: html, css

I am kind of a nooby when it comes to web development and I am still learning. I am a bit stumped on a issue with this navigation bar I am making. What this issue is that the circles that contains the link and text are not correctly making a new circle every time I add a new il line. If anyone could explain to me what I am doing wrong it would be a great help :)

```
Code: http://jsfiddle.net/16eod9Ld/
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your problem. You are not adding `li` with #navigation. I have created a fiddle...https://jsfiddle.net/yvz9j3ot/

Add `li` to #navigation li:hover, #navigation li, #navigation-content li.

Comment: Thank to telling me what is wrong :)

Comment: I hope you have seen the fiddle and I have tried adding more li elements and it works as you want... Glad it helped you !!!

Answer (score 1):

You're applying the border (and border-radius, and width, and height) to the wrapper but instead need to apply it to each `li` element.

See: https://jsfiddle.net/9n574tLe/

You'll need to adjust the :hover stuff to account for that.